# Close android application when mobile sleep after timeout or when power button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-application-class

I am creating a locker application, in which I want to close my application when user presses power button to lock screen or when screen off after timeout. I have tried to do this using onResume(), onPause() function but nothings works perfect.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by kill the current process by

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```